# Check if element value is empty or not with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a input and I want to check if it's empty or not. I am using Wikipedia's API to get information and this is the AJAX part:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: searchedUrl,
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){

      var length = data[1].length;
      var inputValue = $('#searchInput').val();
      console.log(inputValue);

      if (!$('#searchInput').val()){ 
        error = true;
        console.log('err');

      } else {
        if (error = true){
          $('#errorMsg').html('Search error').fadeOut();
        }
        $('.title').css('margin-top', '30px');
        $('#output').removeClass('hidden');
          for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
            $('#output').prepend('<li><a href='+data[3][i]+'>'+data[1][i]+'</a><br>'+data[2][i]+'</li>');
          }
      }
    },
  error: function(err){
    error = true;
    $('#errorMsg').html('Search error').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

However, when it succeeds I want it to check if the value of the input is empty or not. I use that IF condition but it does not writes 'err' in the console. It's like it ignores everything if the value is empty. I've also tried the condition like this:

```
if (inputValue !== ''){

// Error;

}
```

but it's not working.

PS: This is my JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dietic/sdfu967y/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `if(inputValue.length) { ... }`! If the length is `0` then the `if` body won't be executed.

Comment: Why don't you put a debugger and see what was the value at that point?

Comment: The value is "" but it stills does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers but I found out what It wasn't working.
I was trying to get a length of data before checking if there was data or not in this line:

```
success: function(data){

  var length = data[1].length;
  var inputValue = $('#searchInput').val();
  console.log(inputValue);
```

it put the `var length = data[1].length;` after I checked the input and it worked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing an `!==` check, which checks both the type and the value. This means if `inputValue` is `null` or `undefined`, your `inputValue !== ''` will be `true`.

To prevent this, simply do `if (inputValue) { ... }` to check that input value is not `null`, `undefined`, `''`, or `0`.

Comment: On JS line 25 you have `if (error = true)` which should be `if (error == true)`. You should probably also return or throw from that function to prevent running the rest of it.

Comment: Nvm. Thanks for that but I figured what the error was. Ill post it. Thanks anywyas

Comment: *"This means if `inputValue` is `null` or `undefined`"* In the OP's code, `inputValue` will never be `null`. The only way it would be `undefined` would be if there was no element with the `id` `searchInput` or it wasn't a form field. If it's there, and a form field, `inputValue` **will** be a string.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here. But let me clarify this.

Your `inputValue` can be either `undefined`, `null` or `"have something"`.

If you call `if(inputValue) // undefined or null or ""` it will be equal to `if(false)`.

If `if(inputValue) // "blah blah"` it will be equal to `if(true)`.

So first you need to check if it's `null or undefined` first and then call `.length` if you want to make sure it's not empty.

Comment: I just posted that hahaha I realized that before you posted the answer. You can check in the comments I did in Liam Gray a while ago.  That's teh correct answer +1. Thanks anyways!

Comment: This is technically false, `if (inputValue)` will be false for `null`, `undefined`, *and* `''`. Strings of length 0 are false, even though confusingly arrays of length 0 are true.